# Batch operation doesn't get called

Tags: 7, batch-operations

I am trying to write a batch. And I have a problem that none of the batch operations callback functions are getting called.

I wrote `drupal_set_message` at the start of each callback and none of the messages are displayed.

I can get the batch page, but the callback ops aren't called at all.

Here's the code I used:

```
function mymdoule_node_batch()
{
    $batch = array(
        'title'         => t("Migrating"),
        'operations'    => array(
            array('mycallback_001'),
            array('mycallback_002'),
        ),
        'finished'      => 'mycallback_finished',
        'init_message'  => t('Initializing...'),
        'error_message' => t('An error occurred.'),
    );

    batch_set($batch);
    drupal_set_message("step: 0"); // this is the only message the system returns
}


function mycallback_001(&$context)
{
    drupal_set_message("step: 1");
    $nids = db_select("node", "n")
            ->fields("n", array("nid"))
            ->orderBy("nid", "ASC")
            ->execute()
            ->fetchCol();
}

function mycallback_002(&$context)
{
    drupal_set_message("step: 2");
    $nids = db_select("node", "n")
            ->fields("n", array("nid"))
            ->orderBy("nid", "ASC")
            ->execute()
            ->fetchCol();
}
```

P.s. The batch is getting called in form submission.

What's wrong in that?

Comment: add one redirection at the end of mymdoule_node_batch function then check. batch_process(URL_TO_REDIRECT);

Comment: What do you mean by `add one redirection at the end of mymdoule_node_batch`? Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: When I add `batch_process();` before `drupal_set_message("step: 0");` the message is not displayed as well.

Comment: where is your mycallback_finished function. can you add that one to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked after I added `file` to the `$batch` array.

```
function mymdoule_node_batch()
{
    $batch = array(
        'title'         => t("Migrating"),
        'operations'    => array(
            array('mycallback_001'),
            array('mycallback_002'),
        ),
        'finished'      => 'mycallback_finished',
        'init_message'  => t('Initializing...'),
        'error_message' => t('An error occurred.'),
        'file'          => 'mypatch.ops.inc',
    );

    batch_set($batch);
    drupal_set_message("step: 0");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This Problem happens when we put our file in different folder like as includes/form_test.inc.In this scenario batch function can't call.So to handle this we put 'file' => 'path_to_file_containing_myfunctions' in our submit function.

```
    $batch = array(
      'title' => t('Custom File uploader'),
      'operations' => array(
        array('test_feeds_import_form_batch', array($uri)),
      ),
      'progress_message' => t('Uploading Multiple Products...'),
      'error_message' => t('Error!'),
      'finished' => 'test_feeds_import_form_batch_finish',
      'file' => drupal_get_path('module', 'test') . '/includes/test_form.inc',
    );

    batch_set($batch);
    batch_process('admin/import-data'); //Work like as drupal goto
```